# Gorm mapping for inheritance

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm facing a issue regarding inheritance in Grails.
I have a domain class Person.grooy:

```
class Person{
    String name
    String contactNumber
    Address address
}
```

Now I'm extending Person.groovy for Employee and Customer like:

```
class Employee extends Person{
    String designation
}
class Customer extends Person{
    String interest
}
```

Now I want separate table in my database for Employee and Customer having columns of Person i.e name,contactNumber and associate address key. 
How could I achieve this. I searched every where but there is nothing for this aspect.
Is this one approach is not possible in GORM.
Please answer.
Thanks Guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I managed to get what I want just by placing a `grails.persistence.Entity` annotation to my child domain classes. I also make my parent i.e. Person.groovy abstract and place in src/groovy.

Now I have database hierarchy as I expected but some scaffold issues in controller still persist that will also sorted out with your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable table-per-hierarchy, which is by default enabled in Grails

```
class Employee extends Person{
    String designation

static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

[table-per-hierarchy Ref](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceStrategies)

Comment: yes I already tried. It will create table for each domain class separately like for Person It has three column name, contact_number, address_id. And One column in employee table for designation. And also one column for interest in Customer table.

Comment: I want Employee table should have column name,contact_number, address_id and designation. And there should be no table for Person.groovy

Answer (score 4):

If you put your Person class in src/java or src/groovy it won't be mapped to the db.

Remember to import it into your Employee and Customer classes

```
import com.yourPackage.Person

class Employee extends Person{

}
```

Comment: Yes I tried all aspect. Putting my parent class i.e. Person.groovy in src/groovy and import them in child class but there is no mapping in database.
I also tried by putting domain class as abstract and then extending but no luck.
thanks mate for your time and consideration. Hope we will get solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like inheritance is not the approach we need to follow here. You should create composition with Person class and it will store the properties of Person class in Employee.

```
class Employee {
    Person person
    String designation

    static embedded = ['person']
}
```

[Gorm Composition](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#gormComposition)

Answer (score 1):

you can put it inside src/java, but that solution will not be standard, as it really will not be treated as a grails domain example once you get deeper into the application.

For example, if you want to create a controller or a test script on the extended domain as per the previous answer, it will be complicated.

As of grails 2.2.x I believe, grails provides you with **mapWith**. You can use that for a more maintainable solution

```
class Employee{
static mapWith = "none"
}
```